# How to retemplate a user control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I wrote a user control for my project.  Now I want to have a template for it where everything is moved around.

How would I go about doing this?  I'm looking and it seems impossible?  I see many paths on how to do this but what would be the best way?

Some ideas I have:

- Rewrite the user control as a control so it can be templated
- Create a second user control, but have it databind to the same viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the first option.  Rewrite the original control as "Silverlight Templated Control" borrowing from the original UserControl xaml to help you set up the initial default template.

Review the MSDN topic:  [How to: Create a New Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc964292%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

This forms a good basis.  However that example doesn't make enough use of `TemplateBinding`, in your implementation you should make wider use of that.